# How to set camera yaw rotation to another gameobjects yaw rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I would like to set the camera rotation the same way a gameobject is facing.

At the moment this gameobject “A” faces a random way when the game starts so I would like the camera to face that way when it starts too.

The game object is rotated using Quaternions (and maybe Euler angles) but that’s a different object. I would just like the camera to face the direction where the game object is facing on startup (y-axis).

I have tried this scipt on my camera:

```
Vector3 cameraRotation = myCameraObject.transform.eulerAngles;
cameraRotation.y = myTargetObject.transform.eulerAngles.y;
myCameraObject.transform.eulerAngles = cameraRotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Quaternion q = Quaternion.Euler( degxaxis, degyaxis, degzaxis );

q = camera.transform.rotation * q;

transform.rotation = transform.rotation * q;

Comment: the degyaxis is what I need from the other gameobject. I think what is happening is that this script is running before the game object has the chance to move.